# My project is on Google App Engine(webapp2). I am not able to import firebase-admin

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, pip, firebase-admin, webapp2

I am developing my web app using webapp2. I have tried to setup firebase-admin but I am not able to import it. The firebase-admin files are in the lib folder.I have also added the lib folder by vendor.add. 
If I import the firebase-admin using lib.firebase-admin it works. But there are alot of imports in the init.py folder of the firebase-admin. Thus even those imports are not working.

from firebase_admin import auth

The above line of code 
'from firebase_admin import auth' does not work. But 'lib.firebase_admin import auth' works. This is a workaround which isnt feasible.

The stack trace is below:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\controllers\Handler.py", line 10, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\controllers\Home.py", line 22, in get
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\lib\firebase_admin\__init__.py", line 62, in initialize_app
    credential = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\lib\firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 128, in __init__
    self._g_credential, self._project_id = lib.google.auth.default(scopes=_scopes)
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\lib\google\auth\_default.py", line 281, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "C:\Users\Farrukh Bin Rashid\Documents\Internship\Blog-GoogleSearchAPI - Firebase Admin\Blog\lib\google\auth\_default.py", line 111, in _get_gcloud_sdk_credentials
    from google.auth import _cloud_sdk
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\sandbox.py", line 1174, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.auth```
````

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace of the error you are receiving when importing the library?

Comment: I have added the stack trace above. Please check.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your lib folder, adding these libraries to your requirements.txt something like “google-auth>=1.5.0” and “firebase-admin>=1.0.0” then running “pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt”?

Comment: Yes I did. It still isnt working though. The folders in the lib folder arent being detected unless I refer the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.7 on App Engine, you will need to follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) in order to use this library. If you are using Python 3.7, you can just use your requirements.txt and won’t need to use vendor.add().

Comment: You created the appengine_config.py file and it did not work for you? The only way this library will work in GAE standard Python 2.7 is explicitly referring to the lib folder. You would need to follow the 4 steps under “Copying a third-party library” to use this library. However, you won’t be able to use the requirements.txt in Python 2.7 only in 3.7.